# Use of functions in calculation and gas use

Tags: ethereum, solidity

Why is the following not working?

```
uint transactionFee = (msg.value * 2) / 100;
uint transactionReward = (msg.value * 2) / 100;
uint receiverMoney = msg.value - limitTransactionCosts(transactionFee - transactionReward);
```

[The contract won't allow this transaction to be executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agh1N.png)

While this is working:

```
uint transactionFee = (msg.value * 2) / 100;
uint transactionReward = (msg.value * 2) / 100;
transactionFee = limitTransactionCosts(transactionFee);
transactionReward = limitTransactionCosts(transactionReward);

uint receiverMoney = msg.value - transactionFee - transactionReward;
```

[50.002 Gas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4qm0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work as Expected because there is no mistake.
Make Sure the your limitTransactionCosts has a valid return type(int/float).
Please add function code to analyze it further.

Comment: limitTransactionCosts is a function

Comment: OK , It is with '-' symbol in the Question so I assumed

Answer (score 0):

Found my mistake. I send the transaction fee and reward regardless of limitTransactionCosts.

My Code know looks like this:

```
// Calculate costs
    uint transactionCosts = (msg.value * 4) / 1000; 
    transactionCosts = limitTransactionCosts(transactionCosts);

    uint transactionFee = transactionCosts / 2;
    uint transactionReward = transactionCosts / 2;

    uint receiverMoney = msg.value - transactionCosts;
```